# PHP prefixing hex summation value with 1?

Tags: php, hex, integer-overflow

I am working on something which adds several hexadecimal values (base16).

In a regular C program, I do the following:

```
uint32_t test1 = 0x5BE0CD19;
uint32_t test2 = 0x3587272B;
uint32_t test3 = 0x1F85C98C;
uint32_t test4 = 0x428A2F98;
uint32_t test5 = 0x61626380;
uint32_t test6 = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5);

printf( "%08x \n", test6 );
```

The result is:

```
> 54da50e8
```

However, in PHP (my PHP is 64bit) when I apply the same sum with:

```
$test1 = 0x5BE0CD19;
$test2 = 0x3587272B;
$test3 = 0x1F85C98C;
$test4 = 0x428A2F98;
$test5 = 0x61626380;
$test6 = ($test1 + $test2 + $test3 + $test4 + $test5);

echo(sprintf( "%08x \n", $test6 ));
```

I get:

```
> 154da50e8
```

Which oddly makes the number an extra character long with a `1` in front of it.

Is there any reasoning to this behavior, and if so how can I prevent it?

Comment: PHP prints the correct answer, your c-addition just overflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are different because you specifically type your C variables as 32 bits and so the addition overflows, leaving you the result `0x54da50e8`. However PHP integers are the same size as installation, in this case 64-bit, so the arithmetic doesn't overflow and you get the correct sum: `0x154da50e8`. (Note that your `8` width specification to [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is a minimum, hence you get all 9 digits from the result). If you only want a 32-bit result, you need to mask the value of `$test6` appropriately i.e.

```
$test6 &= (1 << 32) - 1;
echo(sprintf( "%08x \n", $test6 ));
```

Output:

```
54da50e8
```